# I can't use TailwindCSS in ViewComponent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, tailwind-css

Nice to meet you, I'm Japanese.

I want to apply TailwindCSS in Rails7 View Component, but it doesn't work.

I also changed the settings in tailswind/config.js but it doesn't work.

The views file has been applied (the top string in the image)

Please tell me if you don't mind.

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './app/components/**/*'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['メイリオ','ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3','Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro','Noto Sans JP', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        cabin: ['Cabin Sketch', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
      width: {
        '50': '12.5rem',
        '88.5': '22.125rem',
        '100': '25rem',
        '160': '40rem',
      },
      aspectRatio: {
        '4/3': '4 / 3',
        '1.91/1': '1.91 / 1',
        '3/1': '3 / 1',
        '4/1': '4 / 1',
        'video': '16 / 9',
      },
      maxWidth: {
        '100': '25rem',
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    backgroundColor: ['responsive', 'odd', 'hover', 'focus'],
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ]
}
```

app/components/header/component.html.erb

```
<div class="text-red-500">Add Footer template here</div>
```

app/components/header/component.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Footer::Component < ViewComponent::Base

end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1jzh.png)

I want to apply TailwindCSS in Rails7 View Component, but it doesn't work.

I also changed the settings in tailswind/config.js but it doesn't work.

The views file has been applied (the top string in the image)

Please tell me if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my `config/tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/assets/**/*.svg',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './app/components/**/*.{erb,css,rb}'
  ],
```

I also have to restart the Rails app in order for the config to pick up.

But be sure to not use `rails server`

Use

```
$ bin/dev
```

Which will spin-up both the server and TailwindCSS watcher.

Another place to check is if you have precompiled assets from following tutorials or the sort. Be sure to clean them up.

```
$ rails assets:clobber
```